# Transfer ethereum out of contract

Tags: solidity

I am able to deposit eth into this contract using the remoteAdd() function, and I can confirm that the eth has been added by using the getBalance() function. However, I am unable to withdraw the contract balance to msg.sender using the withdraw() function. Could someone please help me out, thanks!

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract tictactoe {

    //Making explicit all the variables
    uint256 public playerCount;
    uint public betAmount;
    uint public totalBets;
    mapping(uint => Player) public player;
    address owner;

    //This is the state of the game
    enum State { Waiting, InProgress, Finished }
    State public state;

    //You can only send requests to the original contract address
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    //This is the structure of a player
    struct Player {
        uint _id;
        uint _betAmount;
        address _owner;
    }

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        state = State.Waiting;
        playerCount = 0;
    }

    function remoteAdd() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= 0);
        incrementCount();
        betAmount = msg.value;
        owner = msg.sender;
        player[playerCount] = Player(playerCount, betAmount, owner);
        totalBets += betAmount;
    }

    function () external payable{
        remoteAdd();
    }

    //See how much ether the contract is currently holding
    function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
        return totalBets;
    }


    //Function that increases player count
    function incrementCount() internal {
        playerCount += 1;
    }

    //Function that signals the start of the game once two players have
    //placed bets.
    function beginGame() public {
        require(playerCount == 2);
        state = State.InProgress;
    }

    function endGame() public {
        require(state == State.InProgress);
        state = State.Finished;
    }

    function payout() public returns (bool success){
       require(state == State.Finished); 
       msg.sender.transfer(totalBets);
       msg.sender.call.value(totalBets).gas(7000)("");
       return true;
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        uint bal = address(this).balance;
        msg.sender.transfer(bal);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "unable".

Answer (score 2):

Well, I replicated your code in Remix, and it is working fine. The withdrawal functionality is sending the Ether to the `msg.sender`. The problem here is your `getBalance()`. It is returning the `totalBets`, which you arent deducting anywhere after an whithdrawl. Therefore, I assume you are always incrementing the `totalBets`, but never subtracting it when someone withdrawal, hope this helps.